# How to post to Facebook fan page wall as admin

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using RestFb as a java wrapper to make calls to Facebook graph API. I want to post to my fan page as admin. Currently, all posts appear as my personal posts. I have taken the access_code using "manage_pages" as one of the permissions. Here is my code:

```
public void postOnWall(String wallId, String message, String picture, String link, String linkname, String caption, String description) throws FacebookException {
        facebookClient.publish(wallId+"/feed", FacebookType.class,
                   Parameter.with( "message", message),
                   Parameter.with( "picture", picture), 
                   Parameter.with( "link", link),
                   Parameter.with( "name", linkname),
                   Parameter.with( "caption", caption),
                   Parameter.with( "description", description));
    }
```

and in my calling method:

```
try {
            FacebookService facebookService = new FacebookService("access_token");
            facebookService.postOnWall("page_id", comment, "image", "link", title, "caption", description);
        } catch (FacebookException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have replaced all parameters in double quotes with the actual values. What else is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post as the page itself you need to use the Page Access Token,

To retrieve this you need to:

- Obtain the `manage_pages` permission from the user
- Access the `/me/accounts` connection for that user
- Get the access token for each page from the result of that `/me/accounts` call
- Post to `/{page id}/feed` using the Page Access Token

Comment: Despite the downvote, i'm pretty sure i'm right about this unless there's some detail missing in the original question

Comment: Thanks Igy, I figured out that just now and I didn't downvote your answer. I just needed to use the /me/accounts connection. Simply getting a response by typing https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token="my access token" gives the code.